# Is this a good conversion to typescript? Why this error?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code to resize textarea elements when I need to:

```js
function resize({ target }) {
  target.style.height = '1px'
  target.style.height = +target.scrollHeight + 'px'
}

export function textareaResize(el) {
  resize({ target: el })
  el.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  el.addEventListener('input', resize)
  return {
    destroy: () => el.removeEventListener('input', resize)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to convert this code to Typescript as:

```
function resize(event: Event) {
  const target = event.target as HTMLTextAreaElement
  target.style.height = '1px'
  target.style.height = `${+target.scrollHeight}px`
}

export function textareaResize(el: HTMLTextAreaElement): { destroy: () => void} {
  resize({ target: el })
  el.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  el.addEventListener('input', resize)
  return {
    destroy: () => el.removeEventListener('input', resize)
  }
}
```

but I have this error on line `resize({ target: el })` obviously:

```
Argument of type '{ target: HTMLTextAreaElement; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Event'.
  Type '{ target: HTMLTextAreaElement; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': bubbles, cancelBubble, cancelable, composed, and 17 more.ts(2345)
```

How can I fix it?

Maybe I'm wrong to use change it to this: `function resizeTextArea(event: Event)`, right?

Comment: If I do like you're saying I cannot use that function with `el.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plain object is not an Event:

```
resizeTextArea({ target: element })
```

does not pass an Event to `resizeTextArea`, so TS fails.

One option would be to use `this` instead, typed to the `HTMLTextAreaElement`:

```
function resizeTextArea(this: HTMLTextAreaElement) {
  this.style.height = '1px'
  this.style.height = `${+this.scrollHeight}px`
}

export function textareaResize(element: HTMLTextAreaElement): { destroy: () => void} {
  resizeTextArea.call(element)
  element.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  element.addEventListener('input', resizeTextArea)
  return {
    destroy: () => element.removeEventListener('input', resizeTextArea)
  }
}
```

(if you need the event argument too, you could do `function resizeTextArea(this: HTMLTextAreaElement, event?: Event) {`)

Comment: I love this solution. Can I ask you if that `.call()` is a performance problem?

Comment: Not at all. `.call` is similar to calling a function with a particular parameter.

Comment: Ok last question, why I cannot call function normally? it says to me: `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)` but the signature is `function resizeTextArea(this: HTMLTextAreaElement)`. I do not understnad...

Comment: `this` is like an argument. Since the function relies on `this`, you can't call it without a calling context. So `resizeTextArea()` is forbidden, since no `this` gets passed.

Comment: Oh wow. I'm trying to understand... Do you have a link to send me to study this? I'm going to accept this answer!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 1):

The first question would be: Why does `resizeTextArea` need an `Event` when it only uses the `target` out of it? My naive first refactoring would be:

```
function resizeTextArea(target: HTMLTextAreaElement) {
  target.style.height = '1px'
  target.style.height = `${+target.scrollHeight}px`
}

export function textareaResize(element: HTMLTextAreaElement): { destroy: () => void} {
  resizeTextArea(element)
  element.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  element.addEventListener('input', (e: Event) => resizeTextArea(e.target as HTMLTextAreaElement))
  return {
    destroy: () => element.removeEventListener('input', (e: Event) => resizeTextArea(e.target as HTMLTextAreaElement))
  }
}
```

If you want to stick with `Event` for some reason, you could cast `{target}` to `Event`:

```
function resizeTextArea(event: Event) {
  const target = event.target;
  target.style.height = '1px'
  target.style.height = `${+target.scrollHeight}px`
}

export function textareaResize({ target }: HTMLTextAreaElement): { destroy: () => void} {
  resizeTextArea({ target } as Event)
  element.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  element.addEventListener('input', resizeTextArea)
  return {
    destroy: () => element.removeEventListener('input', (e: Event) => resizeTextArea)
  }
}
```

Just be aware that it's not the most type-safe approach as you are essentially constructing an incomplete `Event` in `textareaResize` which creates an implicit and hard-to-understand contract in `resizeTextArea`: Whoever works in that function needs to be aware that `event` is, in fact, not a full `Event`, but just an object that has a `target` property.

Comment: In the first example I cannot get `element.style.overflow = 'hidden'` to work. `element` is missing?

Comment: apologies – I mixed up the examples. corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass target which is type of HTMLTextAreaElement to function which have parameter of type Event. Try this:

```js
function resize(target: HTMLTextAreaElement) {
  target.style.height = '1px'
  target.style.height = `${+target.scrollHeight}px`
}

export function textareaResize(el: HTMLTextAreaElement): { destroy: () => void} {
  resize({ target: el })
  el.style.overflow = 'hidden'
  el.addEventListener('input', resize)
  return {
    destroy: () => el.removeEventListener('input', (event: Event) => resize( event.target as HTMLTextAreaElement ))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type-system is there to *protect* you ... don't try to "cast" your way around it just to get the code to compile.  The error message is telling you that this object does not support more than 20 things that are expected of "an Event."  And, it's *prima facie* obvious that an "HTML text area element" is not "an Event" and never will be.  Unfortunately you haven't told us why you're trying to do that in the first place.